# Why are no sensors found?

Tags: drivers, temperature, sensors

The "sensors" command reports no sensors found. The following packages are installed:

```
libsensors4/xenial,now 1:3.4.0-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
lm-sensors/xenial,now 1:3.4.0-2 amd64 [installed]
psensor/xenial,now 1.1.3-2ubuntu3 amd64 [installed]
psensor-common/xenial,xenial,now 1.1.3-2ubuntu3 all [installed,automatic]
```

The /etc/modules file contains the following:

```
# Generated by sensors-detect on Tue Aug 16 00:25:16 2016
cpuid
i2c-i801
# Chip drivers
lm63
lm85
```

(Sensors-detect only added the chip drivers; I added the others manually when lm63 and lm85 alone didn't work.)

The system is a P4 on an Intel D915GEV (915 Express chipset.) CoreTemp and SpeedFan running under Windows XP display temperatures and fan speed for this system that appear to be correct.

Thanks for any help.

Update - Here is the detection output from SpeedFan:

```
Win9x:NO  64Bit:NO  GiveIO:YES  SpeedFan:YES
I/O properly initialized
Linked ISA BUS at $0290
Linked Intel 82801FB ICH6 SMBUS at $C800
Scanning ISA BUS at $0290...
SuperIO Chip=LPC47m182
Scanning Intel SMBus at $C800...
LM96000 (ID=$69) found on SMBus at $2E
Found Maxtor 6Y060P0 on AdvSMART
End of detection
```

Does Ubuntu 16.04 support the lm96000 sensor? Is there a separate module for it, and do I need to add that module to /etc/modules? Thanks.

Update - Nobody seems to be able to explain this behavior. Should I submit a bug report for this issue? Thanks.